# GDB pre-make watches and commands

Tags: linux, gdb

I am trying to create a separate file with all the **watches** and **define command** to load into gdb prior to starting debugging. I imagine it working something like this

```
    #debug.info

    watch i

    define sumA
       print $arg0 + $arg1 + $arg2
    end

    b 30
```

And then I just execute the **program.out** with it as an argument.
I imagine it to look something like this

```
gdb program -s debug.info
```

I have been looking in **man gdb** but cannot seem to find it. Would you please be able to help?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read in commands from file you have to use `-x` not `-s`.

From the man page:

```
   -command=file
   -x file
       Execute GDB commands from file file.
```

The `-s` loads a symbol file. Normally your program already has all symbols inside if you have compiled with `-g`. You may split your application and symbols to separate files, but that is typically not what you want.

Comment: That's it. Thank you Klaus.